# [viewcontroller_name tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b3a630'

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]

I am having an app which has a UITableViewController which is my settings page. I am pushing the UITableViewController with a presentModalViewController using self.navigationController (using storyboard ID). however each time I try to see that page, it's showing exception. After reading few posts I tried implementing two methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
**my .h File**

@interface Setting : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

I have done all UI settings in IB so I didn't change anything in above two implemented methods.

In mainviewcontroller from where I am pushing the view to UITableViewController, I am using the below code

```
Setting *nextController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"setting"];
[self presentModalViewController:nextController animated:YES];
Setting *dvc = [[Setting alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

[image: All ui in IB]

As I already set all UIs in IB why do I need to implement those methods? At least I can seen the view correctly.

Comment: What's the superclass of your class?

Comment: what's your super class?

Comment: @H2CO3 its UITableViewController I guess..

Comment: You definitely have some recursion in there, you don't need to be calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` IN `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Do you use static or dynamic prototypes in your table view?

Comment: @Saty **Don't guess, write what the exception message says.**

Comment: If you are using static cells then you do not need to implement those methods, they are handled automatically

Comment: @Dan when I just try to load the view without implementing the methods exceptions comes for numberOfRowsInSection: and  for which class  you are asking the superclass.

Comment: Are you sure you selected "Static Cells" In the table view content dropdown in IB?  Can you also paste the EXACT EXCEPTION that is output in your log?  And I believe the class he is asking the superclass for is the one that you have implementing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` above

Comment: I just uploaded a pic which shows the exception and also shows that I selected static..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to initialize the same viewController twice. You don't need to `alloc] init]` after you `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.` At least, from my experience you don't. Try this:

```
Setting *nextController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"setting"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

That will "push" the `nextController` with the `storyBoardID` of "setting" from the right into your existing `NavigationController`.

However, using my intuition, I believe you want to present a settings view modally, that has it's own `NavigationController`. In that case, try this code, which wraps the Settings `ViewController` into a `NavigationController`, and presents that whole thing modally, so you can navigate within settings:

```
Setting *nextController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"setting"];
UINavigationController *navcont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextController];
navcont.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:navcont animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Alternatively, you could do all of this in the Storyboard itself. Select your settings view controller, and go to Editor Menu > Embed In... > Navigation Controller. Then make a `segue` from your button to the navigation controller that holds the settings controller. Set the segue to "Modal" and you're all done.

Comment: alright @jhilgert00...that I got it and about the above question...I got it working with Dynamic Cell with all my UI working good.

Comment: Do you know why my table is not scrolling fully so my last row is not clearly visible.